# Zabbix not collecting metrics from Mongodb

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb, zabbix

I have a Mongodb running on an ubuntu server for which I have installed zabbix agent2 as per the documentation.
https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/mongodb#mongodb

My zabbix server is running on a different host, the ip address of which has been updated in the config file of zabbix agent2 for passive check.
I have created a user in the mongodb to collect the data for zabbix using the command below
test> use admin;
admin> db.createUser(
{
user: "my username",
pwd : "password",
roles: [ { role:"userAdminAnyDatabase", db:"admin" } ]
}
)

While creating the Front end  I have updated the {$MONGODB.CONNSTRING}:tcp://ipaddress od zabbix server:27017, {$MONGODB.PASSWORD} and {$MONGODB.USER}.
The host availability is green but the latest data is not showing any values.